# Adding gradient text in createjs

Tags: html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I am currently looking for a way to add a gradient to my text object that was generated with textjs.

```
    this.text = new createjs.Text(this.val, this.font, "#efa146");
    this.text.textAlign = "center";
    this.text.y = this.pos.y;
    this.text.x = this.pos.x;

    console.log(this.text);

    window.stage.addChild(this.text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually very easy, just extend the Text object like this

```
<script>
    (function () {
        function GradientText(text, font, color) {
            this.Text_constructor(text, font, color);
        }

        var p = createjs.extend(GradientText, createjs.Text);

        p._drawTextLine = function (ctx, text, y) {
            if (this.gradient) {
                var height = this.getMeasuredLineHeight();
                var my_gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, y, 0, y + height);
                my_gradient.addColorStop(0, "black");
                my_gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");

                ctx.fillStyle = my_gradient;
                ctx.fillText(text, 0, y, this.maxWidth || 0xFFFF);
            } else {
                this.Text__drawTextLine(ctx, text, y);
            }
        };

        window.GradientText = createjs.promote(GradientText, "Text");
    }());
</script>
```

Now just create an instance of `GradientText` like this:

```
 var text = new GradientText("Hello world!", "20px Arial", "#ff0000");
 text.gradient = true;
```

You should see a gradient over text when you add it to the `stage`. Here is the jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/r94zmwxa/

*P.S. I've just written an example (black and white), but you can change the `addColorStop` from the `this.gradient` to set the gradient colors dynamically!*

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this. Sorry. There are plans to add better control on fill and stroke methods for Text in the future.

Comment: Is there any change regarding those features?

Comment: No it's definitely possible, please see my answer below.